# Create sqlite tables dynamically

Tags: android, sqlite, dynamic, onclick

My code is creating sqlite one sqlite table that save the input data on clicking at the add button, what I want to do is every time I click to the button `NewTab` a new table will be created, I searched everywhere and I tried sharedpreferences also to make different name of tables nothing helped me, can any one help plz and thank you.

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Shopping.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Main_table";

public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "PRICE";

public MyDBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,PRICE TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String name,String price) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,price);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}
```

}

**MainActivty**

```
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        MyDBHandler myDb = new MyDBHandler(MainActivity.this);
                        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editName.getText().toString(), null);
                        if (isInserted == true) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();

                            while (res.moveToNext()) {
                                final TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

                                String valor1 = "<p style='font-family:verdana'>" + a + "</p> ";
                                textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(valor1));
                                lin.addView(textView);



                            }


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
```

Comment: If you want to create a new table every time you press the button, you should run a query to drop the older one, ore give it a new name every time by adding a random number to it ( you cannot create a new table with the same name). I still don't recommend recreating the table, you can just wipe the data from it.

Comment: Its not clear from your question that why you want to create a new table. Can you explain in detail what is it that you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Thank you for responding , i tried to change the name of the table but i didn't make it wright because its my first time using sqlite . I can't drop it because at the end i need to retrieve all the tables . My main goal is to make a list every time the user click on a button and the he enter data that will be saved in that list like the toDo list app

Answer (score 0):

make a variable that u save via `sharedPreferences` this is ur `table count` then make a sql Database and then do

```
SQLDATABASENAME.execSql("CREATE TABLE Table" + your_counter_variable_ + " #create rows here ;");
```

Comment: I used shareprefrences like u said but i had a problem , i created the var in the mainActivity to incremented while clicking on the button but when i retrieve this var while creating new database it generated an error

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the actual time that way ud get a unique Id for all tables

Comment: I used it too but no data is insered appears . Could i made my goal with online database plz ??